# Remove trailing spaces automatically or with a shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to remove trailing spaces in Visual Studio Code (automatically or with a shortcut)?

I've been looking for this in the command palette and in the editor settings, but I cannot find what I am looking for.

Comment: [ramhiser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884131/remove-trailing-spaces-automatically-or-with-a-shortcut/48932800#48932800) actually covers the shortcut (manual) part: `Ctrl` + `K`, `Ctrl` + `X`

Answer (score 1691, accepted):

You can enable whitespace trimming at ***file save time*** from settings:

1. Open Visual Studio Code User Settings (menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *User Settings* tab).
2. See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663494/648162) for the GUI setting, or:
3. Click the [image] icon in the top-right part of the window. This will open a document.
4. Add a new `"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true` setting to the User Settings document if it's not already there. This is so you aren't editing the Default Setting directly, but instead adding to it.
5. Save the User Settings file.

We also added a new command to trigger this manually (*Trim Trailing Whitespace* from the command palette).

Comment: Yep, I am now using it since it has been released, thank you to the VS code team :)


And in addition, here's the shortcut to remove trailing space on the current working file: 

    CTRL+SHIFT+X

Comment: Looks like the shortcut on macOS is now Command-K followed by Command-X

Comment: Is there a way to have it enabled for all files but disabled for certain file types? Markdown comes to mind, for example.

Comment: Currently not, but we are looking into language specific settings for this milestone. See our iteration plan here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17608

Comment: Is this answer still correct for VS code 1.38.1? I am not seeing the `{}` icon in the User settings tab.

Comment: @thesamet It's a document icon now, "Open Settings (JSON)"

Comment: As of VS Code 1.42, there is a checkbox "Trim Trailing Whitespaces" (as explained by Shivkumar Birnale). No more JSON to edit.

Comment: [Shivkumar Birnale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884131/remove-trailing-spaces-automatically-or-with-a-shortcut/53663494#53663494)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in the command palette in version 1.43.1 (2020-02).

Comment: @rookie1024, for Python I recommend the "Python Indent" extension with the option "Trim Lines With Only Whitespace". It removes the whitespace left behind when creating an blank line.

Comment: fyi, in the 1.51.1 vs code (MAC), you can search for the `files.trimTrailingWhitespace` in Preference → Settings and toggle the value.

Comment: Cannot find the *Trim Trailing Whitespace* option in the command pallete.... Was it removed?

Comment: @StijndeWitt It is definitely still present. Checked on the latest version (as of now): Version: 1.79.2.

Comment: I would like to limit removing trailing white-space to changed sections, based on the git/vcs status. Is that possible?

Answer (score 293):

Menu *Code* → *Preference* → *Settings* →

[image]

Check the *"Trim Trailing Whitespace"* option - *"When enabled, will trim trailing whitespace when saving a file"*.

Comment: interface changed

Comment: In Codium, it starts with a click on "File" in the menu.

Comment: Can I exclude some types of files from getting their trailing whitespaces trimmed?

Comment: I do just like what the screenshot does. But it doesn't trim the whitespaces when I save a file. What might be going  wrong?

Answer (score 128):

Not only can you change the Visual Studio Code settings to trim trailing whitespace automatically, but you can also do this from the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

[image: Command Palette: Trim Trailing Whitespace]

You can also use the keyboard shortcut:

- Windows, Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

(I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.20.1.)

Comment: On Linux, you can use `Ctrl` + `K` `Ctrl` + `X`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a match using the command palette in Visual Studio Code 1.43.1 (2020-02). (Same result on both Linux and Windows.)

Comment: The keyboard shortcut can be discovered by: 1) Open menu `File` →`Preferences` →`Keyboard Shortcuts`. 2) Type "trail" in the search box (at the top)

Comment: On Mac as of today(July 2020) in VSCode 1.46.1 version, you can open settings by pressing ⌘ + ,  and from there to search trailing whitespace or anything else.

Answer (score 25):

In recent Visual Studio Code versions you can find settings here:

Menu *File* → *Preference* → *Settings* → *Text Editor* → *Files* → (scroll down a bit) *Trim Trailing Whitespace*

This is for trimming whitespace when saving a file.

Or you can search *"Trim Trailing Whitespace"* in the top search bar.

Comment: Had this selected - didn't do what it said (as revealed in git). Hope adding it manually to the user-settings file works.

Comment: Alternative: Type "trim" in the search box after the "Settings" window has been opened (at the top)

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio Code, menu *File* → *Preference* → *Settings* → search for "trim":

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [the EditorConfig plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig).

By using the plugin you can have settings specific for various projects. Visual Studio Code also has IntelliSense built-in for .editorconfig files.

Answer (score 5):

## As of 2023 (with images)

**1)** Go to `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings`:

[image]

**2)** In the search bar type `file trailing`:

[image]

**3)** Check the option

You're all set. Now if you add space(s) at the end of a line (or even consecutive spaces in the middle of a line), once you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, the additional useless spaces will get automatically removed.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest for me was to open the `settings.json` file in the `.vscode` folder in my working folder and insert the above mentioned line:

```json
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
```

Answer (score -3):

There is extension in VS Code. This can also be used.

Name: Trailing Spaces
Id: shardulm94.trailing-spaces
Description: Highlight trailing spaces and delete them in a flash!
Version: 0.4.1
Publisher: Shardul Mahadik
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shardulm94.trailing-spaces

Answer (score -8):

```
<Ctr>-<Shift>-<F>
```

*Format*, does it as well.

This removes trailing whitespace and formats/indents your code.

Comment: This requires setting-up a formatter depending on the language of the document. For example, for Python, need to setup [autopep8, yapf, or black](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting) as the provider.

Comment: You didn't mention if you are using an extension or not