# How can I disable Visual Studio Code auto trimming whitespace of my HTML classes?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, drupal, twig

```
<ul{{attributes.addClass('container container-desktop')}}>
```

when I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (autoformat), all my classes are without whitespace:

```
<ul{{attributes.addClass('containercontainer-desktop')}}>
```

I searched in the settings of Visual Studio Code for a setting. But did not found a solution to disable it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30884131/8780756
Hi, Hope this will help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a correct behavior from your IDE, because `addClass` with a string parameter is meant to add **one class**.

For multiple classes, refer to [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates#s-multiple-classes):

> ```
> {%
>   set classes = [
>     'red',
>     'green',
>   ]
> %}
> <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}></div>
> ```

Comment: I solve it now like that: <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes['red', 'green']) }}></div>
Thank u!

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see if it solves the problem for you.

Open Visual Studio Code and:

- Click menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings.
- Click {} at the top
- It leads you to a *settings.json* file were you'll
  add: "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true
- Save your file.

Comment: That setting is for trimming at file save time and does not affect the OP's problem