# VS Code problem: When I save, rows and spaces add automatically and destroys code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code and when I save, it automatically adds extra spaces and rows in tags and other parts of the code. After I change it back to the previous syntax and save again, this problem repeats and then my code couldn't work.

**Recently I changed some property in my settings, I think it is connected to a "Prettier" extension, and since then I have this problem, but I don't remember which one to enable now in order to fix it.**

For example here is an original code syntax in [JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Cyu.jpg):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  return ( null);
  <div>

  </div>
}

export default App;
```

And this is what [happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq9md.jpg) after I save:

```
import React, {
  useState
} from 'react';

function App() {
  return (null); <
  div >

    <
    /div>
}

export default App;
```

I can't bring it back to correct syntax (delete unnecessary rows and spaces) when I change it back and save again - it does the same thing. I made changes like the offer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122175/automatically-hard-wrap-lines-at-column-in-vscode) (add rewrap) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884131/remove-trailing-spaces-automatically-or-with-a-shortcut) (trim settings), but it didn't help.

I tried to uninstall and then reinstall my program, but it didn't help. My VS code version doesn't have the Tools option that may help.

Comment: You probably didn't configure prettier to understand JSX syntax

Comment: check your visual studio user settings/preferences. There could be settings like `editor.formatOnSave` set to true.. you might have to change it to false to disable the auto format

Comment: The change of formatOnSave worked, I think. Thanks!
@Bergi - I am not sure I understand your answer, though probably disable the formatOnSave was enough.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced a similar issue as shown here:

[image: issue]

Select "JavaScript React" instead of "JavaScript" as shown here:

[image: fixed]

Comment: I was able to use it, however I had to change this option for every other page. Is there a simpler method to automatically apply for additional pages?