# Access settings in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

There is a lot about about changing setting in Visual Studio on stackoverflow. All of them start with go to 'File' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Settings'

Ref: [Remove trailing spaces automatically or with a shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884131/remove-trailing-spaces-automatically-or-with-a-shortcut)

But there is not 'Preferences' when I click on 'File' from top menu.
Could anyone give advise where is settings now/how to get access to them, please

Visual Studio 2019

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You might try Tools->Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Tools->Options, depending on what you wish to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio (one version of which is Visual Studio 2019) is a completely different application from Visual Studio Code. Information about one will not generally be applicable to the other.

For instance, Visual Studio Code has a "preferences" submenu in its file menu, whereas Visual Studio has most of its options available under "Tools->Options". (The preferences themselves will also be different, so this isn't just a matter of finding it in a different menu.)

Comment: Yeap, I missed that VS Code is so different. Thanks