# Remove empty lines in file with VSCode but only at the start and end of file

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Here is my text :

```
     <---- empty line to delete
     <---- empty line to delete
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
     <---- empty line to keep
Lorem ipsum
     <---- empty line to delete
```

Here's what I would like to have using `VSCode` regex, or any extension you might know about.

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
```

Any idea ? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I might need to precise that I want to achieve this on more than 12000 files. So can't imagine doing this manually.. And I haven't found any extensions yet, neither answers about this subject.

Comment: How do you define empty line? Only allowed characters are spaces?

Comment: No. empty empty. No spaces.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884131/remove-trailing-spaces-automatically-or-with-a-shortcut

Comment: @kipy thank you but this is only white spaces, no new lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For empty lines at the end, you can remove them with `\n+$(?![\r\n])` in VSCode.

For the first empty lines should work (?) `(?<!(.|\n))\n+`.

Other flavours of regex have (although they don't seem to work in VSCode) have `\A` or `` \` `` and `\Z` `\'` for start and end of file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, indeed some lines containing special characters at the end, are selected too. But this puts me on track! Let me check.

Comment: `(?<!(.|\n))\n+`
This seems to do the trick, and handles more (all ?) cases.
Maybe you can update your answer with it.
Thanks didn't know it was possible.